# Hierarchical Data Join of parent/child relationship in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
Id  ParentId  Weight
1   1         0
2   1         10
3   2         5
```

`ParentId` references `Id` of the same table.  How can I query this table so that I join it on itself, adding up the cumulative weight of the third column?

For example, if I wanted to know the cumulative weight of Id 2, the result would return 15 (Id2 + Id3 = 15) as the parent of item 3 is 2.  If I wanted to know the cumulative weight of item 3, it would return 5, as no records have a parent id of item 3.

Essentially, if the record I am querying has a child, I want to add the sequence of data's children and return one result.

Is this possible to do in one fell swoop to the database or would I have to loop through the entire record set to find matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [this article](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html#shorter_and_sweeter). If your table is not updated frequently, you can modify a little their `GenericTree` procedure  that it generates all paths for all rows (and call it every time you insert record into the table or update `ParentId` column), store this data into a new table, and then you can perform all the tasks required using simple queries. Personally, I end up with the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tree_for_my_table` (
`rootID` INT(11) NOT NULL, // root node id
`parentID` INT(11) NOT NULL, // current parent id
`childID` INT(11) NOT NULL, // child id (direct child of the parent)
`level` INT(11) NOT NULL, // how far child is from root
PRIMARY KEY (`rootID`, `parentID`, `childID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `childID` (`childID`, `level`)  
 )
```

Populating data for that table doesn't take too long even for a quite large `my_table`.

Answer (score 0):

Last I looked, mysql didn't have a built-in way of doing hierarchical queries, but you can always use a technique such as the adjacency list, discussed (among other techniques) in [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), which encodes the hierarchy in another table and lets you join against that to retrieve subtrees in your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index your tree. See [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for some ways to do this.